# TikZ Horizontal Line Macro Fail

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to create a simple macro that generates an arbitrary number of 8cm horizontal lines.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyLines}[1]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[1]
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,...{#1}}
 \draw (0,\y)--(8,\y);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\MyLines{10}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the code fixed :
I remove [1] in begin tizpicture and add ',' before {#1}

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyLines}[1]
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3,..., {#1}}
    \draw (0,\y)--(8,\y);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

 \MyLines{10}

 COUCOU

 \MyLines{15}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I miss stuff like that... Stupid missing comma and random `[1]`....